# How to export data displayed in current page only in Ag-Grid?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

By default (without passing params), when you export data from ag-grid it exports all data in all pages. How do I set it to export only the displayed data in current page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `shouldRowBeSkipped` param option and define your export function like -

```
export = () => {
        var firstRow  = this.gridApi.getFirstDisplayedRow();
        var lastRow = this.gridApi.getLastDisplayedRow();
        var shouldRowBeSkipped = (params) => {
             // return true if index is less than first row or more than last row
             return params.node.rowIndex < firstRow || params.node.rowIndex > lastRow;
        }
        var params = { 
        shouldRowBeSkipped : shouldRowBeSkipped
        }
      }
```

As per docs -

> **shouldRowBeSkipped**
>   A callback function that will be invoked once per row in the grid. Return true to omit the row from the export.

[Example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-export/#example-selecting-data-to-export) from ag-grid docs

Comment: Thank you so much Pratik Bhat!!

Comment: Glad it helped. If it helped you, you can accept the answer by clicking the tick icon